# grid is missing in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid

[image]

Hello, I'm new to Unity and trying to display grid to my scene. I searched how and someone says I can see show grid in gizmos but I was not able to find it.

Could you tell me where should I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can make it visible from here.

Comment: still not showing.